# Adobe AIR. Local network error

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe

For example, in local network, when Adobe Air is reading files from local server (`\\Server\storage\`) and network will be in down for a second, Air becomes eat a lot of memory and it is increasing up to 1GB (while normal memory use is 100 kb or less).
Just reading file with `File('file path on local server');` from unstable network can cause this error.
Have anybody seen that in projects?

```
  private function init() : void
  {
    file = new File("\\Server\dragracing\results.txt");
    fileStream = new FileStream();
    fileStream.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, fileComplete );
    fileStream.openAsync( file, FileMode.READ );
  }
  private function fileComplete( event : Event ):void
  {
    fileContents = fileStream.readMultiByte( fileStream.bytesAvailable, ISO_CS );
    .....
  }
]]>
```

Comment: You mind showing your code?  It could be your code instead of Air that's causing a severe memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried closing the FileStream in the fileComplete method?  Call the [close method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#close%28%29) to make that happen.

private function fileComplete( event : Event ):void
  {
    fileContents = fileStream.readMultiByte( fileStream.bytesAvailable, ISO_CS );
    fileStream.close();
    .....
  }

Also, based on your code it does not appear that you are ever actually reading information in from the file. from the file; so it is not clear the complete method will ever execute.  There are plenty of methods used to read information in using the [FileStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#eventSummary) class.